# My Racket code didn't run while the equivalent code works well

Tags: compiler-construction, scheme, racket, dsl, beautiful-racket

I am using Racket to write a Domain specific language, I have learned it from beautifulracket.com. When I try to finish my DSL's expander, I want to use macros to transform my DSL into racket code. More specifically, I want to use a macro to implement function call. Here's my code

```
(define-macro (r-eval PARAM ... (r-id ID))
  #'((eval (read (open-input-string ID))) PARAM ...))
(provide r-eval)
```

but when I try to run it, there are some errors: [image: picture]

This chinese DSL code
`一 二之【+】`
is equivalent to `(r-eval 1 2 (r-id "+"))`,which is equivalent to `((eval (read (open-input-string "+"))) 1 2)`, and I use macro stepper to confirm that the macro expand correctly,[image: picture]
but I got an error,`+: unbound identifier; also, no #%top syntax transformer is bound in: +`

I have `(provide +)` yet in my expander.rkt, I don't know what does the error means and why does it happens.Here's my expander.rkt's all code:

```
#lang br/quicklang
(define-macro (r-begin (r-program EXPR ...))
  #'(#%module-begin
     EXPR ...
     ;(display 123)
     ;(define expr-list
     ;  (list EXPR ...))
     ;(display expr-list)
     ;(void (run expr-list))
     ))
(provide (rename-out [r-begin #%module-begin]))

(define-macro (r-expr PARAM ...)
  #' (PARAM ...))
(provide r-expr)

(define-macro (r-eval PARAM ... (r-id ID))
  #'((eval (read (open-input-string ID))) PARAM ...))
(provide r-eval)

(define (run expr-list) 2)
(provide run)

(define (p x y) (+ x y))
(provide p)
(provide +)
(provide eval)
(provide read)
(provide open-input-string)
```

Comment: While not experienced with br I don't think you need `eval`, `read`, or `open-input-string`. Shouldn't the reader be able to convert `一 二之【+】` to  `(+ 1 2)`?

Comment: I think what reader should do is convert  `一 二之【+】` to  `(r-eval 1 2 (r-id "+")),`, which is an AST object (Maybe the name 'object' is inappropriate in  functional languages), and what expander should do is convert `(r-eval 1 2 (r-id "+")),` to `(+ 1 2)`, but because of "+" is a string, I need `eval` `read` `open-input-string` to convert it into a syntax object. That's what I am doing. Anyway, thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give `eval` the second argument, the environment that should containt the definition for `+`. That's what the error message means - that `+` has no definition.

There's a built-in name for the initial environment that you can use there. Look in the documentation for the specifics.